# Laravel performance tuning in Alibaba serverless enviroment

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, alibaba-cloud

I have serverless server in Alibaba cloud with minimum of 30 replicas (4C8G each).

When running load test with 15k concurrent user, the server replicate into 90 replicas which is weird. 90 replicas is too much only for 15k concurrent request.

Normal response time is less than 100ms for each API. When running 15k load test, response time is between 1-4 seconds.

When i investigate, each replicate only can support less than 200 request only which cause the serverless replicate that much.

Is it normal for 4C8G only support less than 200 request concurrent user with full 100% CPU? I check with `htop` 4C is full but RAM is about 2-3 GB used

Below is my config;

Docker - Webdevops Ubuntu

Nginx

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 10000;
}
```

Default.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 180s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;
    }
```

www.conf

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 70
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_spare_servers = 60
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

Opcache

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=512
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=64
opcache.max_accelerated_files=20000
opcache.validate_timestamps=0
opcache.save_comments=1
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

composer.json

```
"Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
"@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
"@php artisan config:cache",
"@php artisan view:clear",
"@php artisan view:cache",
"@php artisan route:cache",
"@php artisan storage:link",
"@php artisan queue:restart",
"@php artisan ide-helper:generate",
"@php artisan ide-helper:meta"
```

Is there any config i missed?